# will_paginate generates wrong number of page links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am Using will paginate 3.0.2 and Rails 3.1.0.

The following code lives within my controller.

```
  @users = User.visible_for(current_user).
           includes(:study_courses).
           ordered_by_last_name.
           page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
```

In a partial where `@users` has been assigned with `users` from above I do:

```
= will_paginate users, previous_label: h("<"), next_label: h(">")
```

If there are 20 Users it gives me 6 page links, where the first page contains 20 users, the second page contains 10 users and of course the remaining pages contain zero users.

I can not figure out why there are 6 page links generated instead of 3.

UPDATE:
Figured out that will_paginate does not use distinct to count the records. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I found a solution on my own:

```
  user_count = User.visible_for(current_user).count(distinct: true)
  @users = User.visible_for(current_user).
                includes(:study_courses).
                ordered_by_last_name.
                paginate(page: params[:page],
                         per_page: 20,
                         total_entries: user_count)
```

In my scope I use disctinct, but calling `count` on the relation seems to overwrite that. So one has to count by hand and pass the count into the paginate method.

Answer (score 1):

This way looks cleaner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10740732/2599681

I tried it and works nicely with Rails 3.2.11 and WillPaginate 3.0.4.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `.count` gives wrong number, too. Because `.count` runs SQL whitch includes "distinct". I changed it to `.length` and it works fine.

Like this

```
user_count = User.some_scopes.length
@users     = User.some_scopes.paginate(page: params[:page],
                                       per_page: 20,
                                       total_entries: user_count)
```